# How to use arbitrary directory as static directory in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a website written in React.
The website itself works fine.

I also have blog which is based on Wordpress.

When I put blog contents on blog directory, React show the 404 not found page because all contents but ***static*** is managed by React.

I think if I could set one more directory ***called blog*** as static directory, I can put all Wordpress related files on the directory.

But I was struggling to do that.

Is there any options or setting files for react-scripts build?
like `react-scripts build --static-directories static,blog`
Could you please help me?

`/index.html
/static/* < static contents
/blog/* < also static contents.`

Thanks in advance.

[UPDATE] even though i put static file on static directory, I could not access it. It turned out I need to import that static file from Reactjs file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED] Problem was 2 folds.
Server-side and client-side.

First, I edited the .htaccess file not to rewrite anything.
`RewriteEngine off`

Now Safari can understand ***"my domain/blog/"*** correctly.

But Chrome still treat ***"my domain/blog/"*** in ReactJS.

I don't understand why but I can see correct no-React contents only once after deleting cache. But once I open React contents, Chrome start treating ***"my domain/blog/"*** as React contents again.

Then I checked source code again and found that I used a React Router's feature called ***Switch***. It seems ***Switch*** is doing rewriting thing in React.

So I removed the Switch tag and finally problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you probably want to deal with on a server level.

So if you are using express, then you can do something like:
`app.use('/static', express.static('public'))`