# How to use legacy web site and ReactJS both?

Tags: reactjs, url-rewriting, browser-cache

I have a React app which is created by create-react-app command.
And I also have the blog system which is based on Wordpress.

Directory structure is like this.

```
*/index.html  
/service-workder.js  
/manifect.json  
/index.html  
/favicon.ico  
/asset-manifest.json  
/static/media  
       /js  
       /css  
/blog <--------------------- Wordpress*
```

When I access the URL by http:mydomain/blog/, 
Firefox show React page instead of Wordpress page.
Firefox even show React page for     http:mydomain/blog/nonexisting    ,
which I think is supposed to provide 404 not found from web server.

I was struggling to find a way ***NOT*** to let React take wildcard paths.

Safari use React only for index.html, which is good.
Chrome, Firefox use React for entire wildcard paths, even for not existing paths.

[http://**myserver**/](http://__myserver__/) ---> should show React app
[http://**myserver**/nonexistence](http://__myserver__/nonexistence) ---> should show 404 from server

Please help me to figure out isolate React app only for exact index.html.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe this have nothing to do with React, seems like question about web server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Like I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47663790/1202679), the root cause was service worker which seems to be HTML5 feature to make a web site to a web app.
Unregistering service worker was the solution.